# need help with material nodes- accidentally tampered with them

Tags: cycles-render-engine, materials, node-editor

[image][image][image][image]Having trouble with blender. I had just managed to make a material on the walls as pictured, iridescent and shiny. I have somehow messed with the nodes and now it has turned black and looks completely wrong. I will attatch pics of before and after and the nodes. Could anybody tell me which part I have tampered with to ruin the image? desperate to get the original material back as I have a deadline tomorrow.
enter image description here

Comment: it would be better if you can add your blend file or post pics of your material set up.

Comment: sorry they should be there now!!

Comment: Try getting rid of that glossy node connected in the volume socket

Comment: I have tried that and still not working :(

Comment: ok give me a sec. Trying to recreate

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a much simpler node set up for you.

Essentially all you are seeing is the noise texture. You dont need all that other stuff.

Also the sockets have to plug into the same color (you can break this rule sometimes, but not in your case.)

[image]

[image]

You can use something other than a noise texture to have a different type of bump.

[image]

Or even better just use this set up since you want shine and bump.
[image]

Comment: You have absolutely saved me. Thank you so so much you legend

Comment: No problem, please mark it as accepted so it helps others, also the bottom node set up is if you wanted a little bit of shininess on the walls.

Comment: Sorry one more question before I accept it. How can I make it look more like bumpy shiny glass? I turned the roughness down to 0 of the glossy, and mode to sharp. Hasnt really done much.

Comment: updated with new image

Comment: also I probably should have plugged that purple bump node into the purple layer weight node to be more correct, but it wont matter much.

Comment: amazing just seen this. THanks so much man